# Why did Peter Allan Fields leave "Deep Space Nine"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, behind-the-scenes

I know that staff turnover on a long-running (and complicated) television show like "Star Trek: Deep Space Nine" is common, but does anyone know any specific details behind the departure of producer Peter Allan Fields after season two?

I was browsing through an episode guide the other day and noticed that the episodes where he received writing credit are among DS9's best (e.g. "Duet", "The Circle", "Necessary Evil", "In the Pale Moonlight"). Did he leave to work on other projects? Was he more interested in writing than all of the other work that goes into producing TV?

---

To clarify, I am curious why he left his staff position as producer.  I'm aware that he continued writing the occasional teleplay for the show. I just wonder if there was some behind-the-scenes reason for his departure.

The third season (and beyond) marked a shift in focus for the show (from the political and religious conflicts on Bajor to the Dominion); you have to wonder if that played any role in his departure.

Comment: In DS9, [seasons 3 and 4 were the only ones he didn't write for](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Peter_Allan_Fields); why do you say he left?

Comment: @Izkata, see my clarification. :)

Comment: “The third season (and beyond) marked a shift in focus for the show (from the political and religious conflicts on Bajor to the Dominion); you have to wonder if that played any role in his departure.” Or if his departure helped cause the shift.

Answer (score 6):

There are several **unsubstantiated rumours** on the internet that he was removed as a staff writer and producer in 1994 as a consequence of Ira Behr becoming the show's Executive Producer and showrunner.

Clearly this wasn't something that resulted in their not being able to work together, as evidenced by his return to write several episodes of DS9 in 1997-1999 although it does beggar the question whether these were written *prior* to his departure and then recycled for later use.

---

With the exception of 2 co-writer credits in 1995 (Legend + Xena) and 3 writer credits in 1997-1999 (DS9) [Peter Fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Allan_Fields) seems to have gone into a well-deserved retirement at the age of 81 after a long and successful career on shows like "The Man from UNCLE", "Knight Rider" and "The Six Million Dollar Man".

The [DS9 companion](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Deep-Space-Nine-Companion-Star/dp/0671501062) specifically refers to him having "*retired*" from the writing staff (e.g. as opposed to simply leaving):

> And, in fact, long after Fields retired from the show at the end of
>   Season 2, the writing staff continued to throw in references to stem
>   bolts, as well as create other terms that sounded "Fields-like," as an
>   occasional tip of the hat to their former comrade

---

If you want to go full-on stalker, you're welcome to try to "friend him" on his [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Peter-Allan-Fields/133061290066511) and ask him directly :-)

Comment: It would be pretty difficult for Fields to have written episodes like 'For the Uniform' and 'In the Pale Moonlight' before he left the staff at the end of Season 2. Especially 'Moonlight', which was predicated on a Dominion War when we hadn't really even met the Dominion by the end of Season 2.

Comment: @Algernon_Asimov - 'Moonlight' shares a writing credit with Michael Taylor. Fields may have written the story but it could just have been a generic one that they've adapted.

Comment: “If you want to go full-on stalker, you're welcome to try to "friend him" on his facebook page and ask him directly” — what on earth do you mean, “if”?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Perhaps Valorum was allowing for the possibility that normal people exist who observe basic etiquette and respect people's boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

According to [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0276333/) he worked on DS9 from 1993 - 1999 except for 1995/1996, during which years he was writing for [Xena: Warrior Princess](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112230/), in 1995 he also wrote for [Legend](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112045/).

He was also Producer for 26 episodes of DS9 and co-producer for 18 episodes, some of which over-lap (he was writer and co-producer).

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question on why he left.

Comment: @BBlake, I understood the question to be "why did he seemingly stop writing after season 2" he left (but returned, he wasn't fired) to work on other projects. Why he decided to take on other work whilst in the middle of writing (& co-producing) for DS9 is unknown (& a different question)